# Vega Lite Bar Width Resizing

Tags: vega-lite, vega

Very new to Vega. Ran into a formatting question:

I have a basic bar chart that can have anywhere from one to 10 dimensional values on the y-axis. The number of dimensional values is dynamic based upon user input.

-When selecting at minimum three values, the is formatted reasonably and looks quite good.

-When selecting only one value, the chart becomes one large square (as a result of resizing).

Is there a way of defining maximum width one bar can take relative to the size of the chart? A slight nuance is that this chart is dynamic in size, meaning it can be expanded to fit full screen.

I'm open to any suggestions that would make one dimensional value bar look good. Again, I'm very new to Vega.

Thanks all!

[Two Dimensional Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvVpl.png)

[One Dimensional Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRL2k.png)

..